# PrimeNG error while loading in Universal mode

Tags: angular, primeng, angular-universal

When I load with `ng serve`, table works fine without any errors. But when I run it in ssr mode with Universal, I get the following errors:

> ERROR { NullInjectorError:
>   StaticInjectorError(AppServerModule)[ScrollableView -> Table]:
>   StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[ScrollableView -> Table]:
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for Table!

I searched and someone mentioned to add `Table` to provider, but didn't work. My shared module:

```js
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';
import { Table } from 'primeng/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  providers: [ Table ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TableModule
  ],
})
```

Angular Version: 8.0.2

Comment: Import `TableModule` as well.

Comment: @ritaj Thanks, but still the same error.

Comment: Why are you providing `Table` like a service?

Comment: @R.Richards First, I didn't provided it. Then I read the error and guessed that I may provide the `Table`.

Comment: I see now. That makes sense. I would have tried the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Please change your module like that

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [],
  providers: [ Table ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    TableModule
  ],
  exports: [
    TableModule
  ],
})
```

Comment: Thanks, but no difference. Still getting the same error.

Comment: Do you another library in your components of module?

Comment: I imported other module's of PrimeNG (file, dropdown, etc). But I only have problem with `TableModule`